# How to make table cell's accessoryView appear on top of highlight?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I'm dynamically adding an accessoryView to my [UITableVieCell](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCell) when it is tapped. It appears to me that the cell highlight is blocking the accessoryView. I don't see my acessoryView until the highlight disappears via tapping a different table cell.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath 
                           animated:YES 
                     scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    UITableViewCell* cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Loading server stuff";

    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 20, 10);
    button.frame = frame;
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The highlight of a cell swaps the background of all the views within. Place an image of your button with this instead:

```
- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)
```

That way, the background is swapped, but the image remains on top.